# Why roll is unpredictable when pitch is close to 90 degrees?

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

While playing with `Sensor Manager`, I noticed that sensor data has some limitations that I cannot understand.

By listening for sensor events, we can extract azimuth, pitch and roll values. [Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-sensor-orientation/index.html?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training#0) is tutorial from Google Codelabs.

```java
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, mAccelerometerData, mMagnetometerData);
SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationValues);

float azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[0]);
float pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[1]);
float roll = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[2]);
```

Now the problem is that roll becomes unpredictable (by changing its value in the wrong way very frequently) when pitch is close to 90 degrees.

I found confirmation of this issue in [Beginning Android Wearables](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484205181) book, but as mentioned, explanation is outside the scope of the book.

> Third, with the conventions described above, azimuth, pitch, and roll
>   becomes finicky and unpredictable when the pitch has values close to
>   90 or -90 degrees. This problem is not related to the hardware sensors
>   but to the mathematics behind azimuth, pitch, and roll. A detailed
>   explanation of gimbal lock is outside the scope of this book, but its
>   ramifications are straightforward: don’t trust the orientation when
>   pitch is close to +/- 90 degrees. If these values of pitch are
>   unavoidable for an application, consider using rotation matrices or
>   quaternions.

**Question**

Could someone explain it a little bit more? How bubble level apps (e.g. [Bubble level](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.androgames.level)) resolves this problem in Android?

Comment: The problem is that Euler angles are not appropiate for situations when the pitch is at or near 90 degrees. This is commonly known as gimbal lock. Here is a simple explanation: http://www.chrobotics.com/library/understanding-euler-angles